# How to edit repeating fields in a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

How would I edit repeating fields in a form (multiple values for same model property)? I am using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework code first with the Razor syntax.

I have managed to get the create functionality working which adds the data to the database successfully but how would I go about bringing these values back into the edit view to edit and re-save back to the database? e.g.

**How My View Looks**

**Enter Description |  Enter Amount**

Description1TextBox  | Amount1TextBox

Description2TextBox |  Amount2TextBox

Description3TextBox |  Amount3TextBox....

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Options[i].Description, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-6" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Options[i].Amount, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-6" })
    </div>
}
```

**My ViewModel**

An Array

```
...
public string Description { get; set; }
public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
public Options[] Options { get; set; }
...
```

**My Create Controller Post ActionResult**

```
....
foreach (var optionsLoop in viewModel.Options)
{
    if (optionsLoop.Description != null || optionsLoop.Amount != null)
    {
        var options = new Options()
        {
            Id = getId,
            Description = optionsLoop.Description,
            Amount = optionsLoop.Amount
        };
        db.Options.Add(options);
    }
}
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

What do I need to change to bring the values back into the edit view to then edit? I can do a Linq query in the **edit controller** action to return a list to get the values I want in my edit view but how do I pass these values from the Linq query to the loop in my view?

```
...
//Values to bring back into my edit view
var getOptions = (from options in db.Options
                  where options.Id == currentUser.Id
                  select new { options}).Take(5).ToList();
...
```

Comment: By assigning it in a property of your model? You need to show more relevant code if your question is _"How"_.

Comment: I added a bit more code, I need to know how to pass the array into the text boxes in the for loop in the view

Comment: `var model = new FooModel { Options = getOptions }; return View(model)`...

Comment: You need to populate your model with the Options in the GET method (see @CodeCaster comment) and in the view use `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)` and change the property to `List<Options> Options`

Comment: Thanks both, your solutions combined worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you model property to

```
public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
```

and in the controllers GET method, assign it using

```
model.Options = getOptions; // populate the options
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
{
  <div class="row">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Options[i].Description, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-6" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Options[i].Amount, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-6" })
  </div>
}
```